# How is Ethereum gas distrubuted to miners?

Tags: mining

How is ethereum gas emitted to miners exactly?   The more you mine, the more gas you earn?  How does the Gas/Ethereum get to the miners wallet?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a transaction you have to set the maximum gas to use (gasLimit), and price you are willing to pay for a unit of gas (gasPrice).

When the transaction is executed the exact gas used will be calculated (gasUsed). Then the sender will be charged with gasUsed * gasPrice, and it will be added to the rewards of the block.

For example let's say your transaction has gasLimit = 120000, gasPrice = 0.000000003 Ether (3 Gwei). When it was executed it used 50000 gas. Then you will charged with 50000 * 0.000000003 = 0.00015 Ether.

Let's say your transaction was the only transaction in the block then the miner will receive a reward of 5.00015 Ether, 5 are from the block reward, and the remaining 0.00015 Ether are from the gas used.

The precise mechanims how it is done is described in the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).